# How to have gameobjects patrol randomly?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a fishing game and I wanted to know if there's a way for me to have the GameObject choose a waypoint randomly so that they don't all follow the same pattern.

```
public class Simple_AI_patrol : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform[] wayPoints;
public float speed;
public int currentPoint;
public bool doPatrol = true;
Vector3 velocity;
Vector3 moveDirection;
Vector3 target;
Rigidbody rb;


void Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
}


void FixedUpdate () {
        if(currentPoint < wayPoints.Length){
            target = wayPoints [currentPoint].position;
            moveDirection = target - transform.position;
            velocity = rb.velocity;

            if(moveDirection.magnitude < 1){
                currentPoint = Random.Range (0, wayPoints.Length);// or currentPoint++
            }else{
                velocity = moveDirection.normalized * speed;
            }
        }else{
            if(doPatrol){
                currentPoint = 0;
            }else{
                velocity = Vector3.zero;
            }
        }
        rb.velocity = velocity;
        transform.LookAt (target);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in your Start function to give a fairly unique seed to the random number generator.

Random.InitState((int)System.DateTime.Now.Ticks);

Comment: Be warned that if you instantiate all your autonomous agents on the same tick, they'll end up with the same seed. This is still probably the best option though.